# Работа с двумя таблицами mysql в php

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, таблицы

Ребята, привет.
Столкнулся с проблемой. У меня есть форма к которой подключена БД, и я хочу заполнять таблицы, я сделал для таблиц условия. Вроде все работает, заполняется первая таблица "psychology". Но вторая таблица не заполняется "popd".
Вот код страницы

```
   <?php
  session_start();

$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'items');

    if (!$connect) {
        die('Error connect to DataBase');
    }
    
    $Student = $_SESSION['user']['full_name'];
$Exercise = $_POST['ex'];
$thing = $_POST['tex'];
$Text=$_POST['details'];


if($thing === 'Социальная психология'){

mysqli_query($connect, "INSERT INTO `psychology` (`id`, `Student`, `Thing`, `Exercise`,  `Text`, `File`) VALUES (NULL, '$Student', '$thing', '$Exercise', '$Text', NULL)");

header('Location: ../course/412course.php');
}else{echo 'ошибка';
}
if($thing === 'Правовое обеспечение профессиональной деятельности'){

    mysqli_query($connect,  "INSERT INTO `popd` (`id`, `Student`, `Thing`, `Exercise`,  `Text`, `File`) VALUES (NULL, '$Student', '$thing', '$Exercise', '$Text', NULL)");
    header('Location: ../course/412course.php');
}else{echo 'ошибка';
}

    ?>
```

Буду благодарен вашей поддержки.

Comment: После второго mysqli_query пишешь echo "INSERT INTO `popd` (`id`, `Student`, `Thing`, `Exercise`,  `Text`, `File`) VALUES (NULL, '$Student', '$thing', '$Exercise', '$Text', NULL)"; Если выведет - вставь строку в SQL вручную, увидишь что за ошибка. Если не выведет - ошибка в условии if

Comment: нашел проблему.
В id не стояло auto_increment.
:---)

Comment: вам  бы начать с чтения каких-нибудь начальных книг по базам данных. чтобы не было желания для каждого предмета отдельную таблицу городить